# Emacs: yes-or-no-p in Russian?

Tags: emacs

I'm using

```
(fset 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p) ;; Make all "yes or no" prompts show "y or n" instead.
```

to anwser yes-or-now questions. Is there a way to append russian analogues as a possible answers? So that y and russian letter н will stand for "yes", while n and т will stand for "no"?

Comment: Do you have your cyrillic letters mixed up or do I?

Comment: Well keyboards are different across the world. If I'm not mistaken mine layout is called 'qwerty'. For example in France - they use a little bit different one - and I could not type in English with 10 fingers there...

Comment: I have no idea why you mention that. The point of my question is that "no" in Russian is "нет", so I'm confused why you want "н" to stand for "yes".

Comment: @Marcin: 'y' and 'н' are on the same key on some keyboards.

Comment: @Marcin: oh I got you wrong. J.F. Sebastian solved it. I don't want to change the question - so it will be asking y-or-n - that's why I'd rather strike н instead of д ("да" means "yes" in russian)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the `y-or-n-p` documentation

> Ask user a "y or n" question.  Return t if answer is "y". Takes one
>   argument, which is the string to display to ask the question. It
>   should end in a space; `y-or-n-p' adds`(y or n) ' to it. No
>   confirmation of the answer is requested; a single character is enough.
>   Also accepts Space to mean yes, or Delete to mean no.  (Actually, it
>   uses the bindings in `query-replace-map'; see the documentation of
>   that variable for more information.  In this case, the useful bindings
>   are`act', `skip',`recenter', and `quit'.)

So you need to add keys to the `query-replace-map`
Something like this

```
;; use the Russian 'н' (which is on the same
;; physical key as 'y') or 'т' (which shares
;; the key with 'n') in query-replace-map
(define-key query-replace-map "н" 'act)
(define-key query-replace-map "т" 'skip)
```

Comment: the OP asks how to use the same key regardless of the current layout i.e., in both cases the *same* key `'y'` is pressed for `'yes'` but sometimes current layout might be Russian that might produce `'н'` instead of `'y'`.